# How to resolve logging out of Facebook with Selenium using Java

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, xpath

I have searched high and low on how to logout of Facebook with Selenium. I've pored through questions on StackOverflow, and many other sites that cover this subject using Selenium, although unsuccessful. I am learning Selenium, and thought it to be pretty straightforward until faced with this hurdle. No matter what I do, Selenium will not logout of Facebook. Below is the code that I'm using. I appreciate any direction (I used Firepath to get the xpath address):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GetFacebookTitle {

public String bu="https://www.facebook.com";
public WebDriver driver;



@BeforeSuite
public void betest(){
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(bu);
    }

@Test(priority=2)
public void test2()
{
    String tilte=driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(tilte);
}

@Test(priority=1)
public void test1()
{
    driver.get(bu);
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("name@hotmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("mypassword");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).submit();
    //System.out.println(title);
    }

@Test(priority=3)
public void test3()
{   
    WebElement lstitem=driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel"));
    lstitem.click();
    lstitem.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[17]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[16]/a/span/span")).click(); //This line just does not work xpath


    }
```

}

Here is the error that is returned:

```
Facebook
PASSED: test1
PASSED: test2
FAILED: test3
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/div[17]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[16]/a/span/span"}
Command duration or timeout: 33 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit:       http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'RLaptop', ip: '192.168.xx.x', os.name: 'Windows  10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false,   handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=45.0.1, platform=WINDOWS,   nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true,   locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true,  javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: c5781a63-5d20-4a55-9cd6-7cd70aa38165
*** Element info: {Using=xpath,    value=html/body/div[17]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[16]/a/span/span}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:198)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebElement.java:295)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:194)
at Testing.GetFacebookTitle.test3(GetFacebookTitle.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:  {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/div[17]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/u l/li[16]/a/span/span"}
For documentation on this error, please visit:     http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11      19:03:33'
System info: host: 'RLaptop', ip: '192.168.xx.x', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at <anonymous   class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Rozelle/App Data/Local/Temp/anonymous1905752364377844577webdriver-  profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10723)
at <anonymous  class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findChildElement(file:///C:/Users/Rozelle/AppData /Local/Temp/anonymous1905752364377844577webdriver- profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10735)
at <anonymous  class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/Rozelle/AppD ata/Local/Temp/anonymous1905752364377844577webdriver- profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12614)
at <anonymous  class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Rozelle/AppDat a/Local/Temp/anonymous1905752364377844577webdriver- profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command- processor.js:12619)
at <anonymous  class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/Rozelle/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1905752364377844577webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12561)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
lstitem.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[17]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[16]/a/span/span")).click();
```

use the below line and it should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Log Out")).click();
```

Comment: I tried adding that line, but it still does not logout.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the sleep (or you can use Explicit Wait). I am unable to post the entire code here, so posted the code on my blog also included a GIF that shows the complete run of the code through logout. [Facebook Logout Using Selenium WebDriver](http://www.mrmoin.com/stackoverflow/selenium-webdriver-stackoverflow/logout-from-facebook-using-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: That worked! I'm curious to know why did you have to use the "throws InterruptedException"?

Comment: That is because we have used Thread.sleep(); in the program. You can catch it with throws or surround it in try/catch block, or the best way to handle is using explicit wait (WebDriverWait or Fluent Wait).

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the click action on Facebook's drop down to show the Log Out form, the page executes Javascript to append that drop down HTML to the DOM.  The problem you're having is, Selenium is not refreshing it's view of the DOM, and therefore, cannot find your element.  Khaja's method works because you're telling Selenium to query the new DOM instead of referencing it's cached one.

Comment: @bmt I tried Khaja's method, but it did not work. Anything else that I need to do?